# set HTML data attribute as an integer array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

HTML code is shown below:

```html
<div class="item_group"  data-item_ids='<%=item_ids%>'></div>
```

In the rendered view it appeared as below:

```html
<div class="item_group" data-item_ids="[22, 33, 19, 21]"</div>
```

Why this integer array of values appeared within double quotes? So, if we take the value of this data attribute, it returns the value as string:

```
  item[group_id] = ($(this).attr("data-item_ids"))

 "[22, 33, 19, 21]"
```

How can I retrieve the value as an integer array, in order to pass the controller and get in the action as an integer array.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why this integer array of values appeared within double quotes?

Because that's the type of quotes the HTML renderer uses. It's standard to use double quotes (`"`) to delimit attribute values in HTML, not single quotes (`'`).

> it returns the value as string. How can I retrieve the value as an integer array?

It returns a string because you're using `attr()`. If you want to work with the values as an array you can call `JSON.parse()` on that string:

```js
let attr = $('.item_group').attr('data-item_ids');
let arr = JSON.parse(attr);

console.log(typeof attr, attr);
console.log(typeof arr, arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item_group" data-item_ids="[22, 33, 19, 21]"></div>
```

Also note that you can avoid the need to manually parse the string by using jQuery's `data()` method. This will automatically determine the type of the value in the `data` attribute and perform the type coercion for you:

```js
let ids = $('.item_group').data('item_ids');

console.log(typeof ids, ids);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item_group" data-item_ids="[22, 33, 19, 21]"></div>
```